# Angular change input value on click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input, increment

I have an input that has a value received as input from another component:

```
    <input [value]="myInput.something">
    <span (click)="incrementPlus()">+</span>
```

I would need a simple function that increases the value of the input at each click by a number of my choice.
It's a very simple thing except that the input value is passed to me in: 
 `@Input() myInput: number;`

 and I don't have to create a variable where I save the value, as I have to repeat / reuse it on many other inputs.
I repeat: it is normally simple as I could pass the @ input into the function, modify it, save it in a variable and then pass the variable to the html input value. But I have to reuse it on other html inputs, and writing lots of variables doesn't seem like a good practice to me.


It's not like all the other questions I've seen before, as they all change a value statically, or wrap it in a variable, and I don't want to do this.

Comment: `<span (click)="myInput.something = myInput.something + 1">+</span>` incrementing from the template is a suitable option for you?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.... the html input value remains the same anyway

Comment: Did you try to work with NgModel?
NgModel will support the two-way binding.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot change it ... the value was entered by other colleagues for other reasons, if I change it other things break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the value **in the parent components too**, you will need to work with @Output and two-way-binding. When you input change, you will call the emit of the output EventEmitter to notify the parent the value has changed.

For two-way-binding, the output must be named like your input, plus `Change`.

In the child, you put :

```
@Input() something: number;
@Output() somethingChange = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

And in the parent :

```
[(something)]="theValue"
```

Then when you `somethingChange.emit` some value, it changes the parent's one, and it passes it to your child too.

Here is a full example :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-en58l5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts